# JS: Transform list into a list which has multiple lists that has all objects between some indices

Tags: javascript

I can't describe my problem very well. So I will give u an example:

I have a list of objects: [o0,o1,o2,...] and want to generate a
list which has multiple lists that has all objects between the in indices i*5 - i*5 + 4.

the result would look like:

```
[[o0...o4],[o5...o8],...]
```

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tired

Comment: This is called `chunking`.

Comment: @YuriyYakym thanks man, i'll look into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by chunking.
You can use one of popular libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk), or implement your own function like this:

```js
function chunkArray(array, chunkSize) {
  return Array.from(
    { length: Math.ceil(array.length / chunkSize) },
    (_, index) => array.slice(index * chunkSize, (index + 1) * chunkSize)   
  );
}
```

Then your code will look like

```js
const array = ['o1', 'o2', 'o3', 'o4', ..., 'o10'];
const result = chunkArray(array, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
let list = [o0, o1, o2, o3, o4, ....];
let result = [];
let i =0;

while(i < list.length ){
let obj = [];
for(let j = 0; j < 4; ; j++){
   if( i >= list.length ){
      break;
   }
   obj.push(list[i]);
   i++;
}
result.push(obj);
}

console.log(result);
```